# blogspot data:navMessage

Tags: blogger, blogspot

I successfully changed these navmessage texts by javascript:

```
<div class='status-msg-body'
           <script
     var str=&#39;<data:navMessage/&#39;;

     str2=str.replace(&quot;Visualizzazione dei post in ordine di pertinenza per la query&quot;,&quot;Articoli
 contenenti:&quot;).replace(&quot;Visualizzazione post con
 etichetta&quot;,&quot;Articoli appartenenti alla
 categoria:&quot;).replace(&quot;Nessun post corrispondente alla
 query&quot;,&quot;Nessun articolo contiene&quot;);


     document.write(str2);
     </script
         </div
```

But if I search a phrase with apostrophe, eg. dog's, the navmessage is blank
There is a way to solve this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Javascript is not necessary. The better way to edit this messages is replacing every `<data:navMessage/>` with:

```xml
<b:if cond='data:numPosts == 0'>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.searchLabel'>
        No posts for label: <b expr:data-search="data:blog.searchLabel"/>.
    <b:elseif cond='data:blog.searchQuery'/>
        No posts for query: <b expr:data-search="data:blog.searchQuery"/>.
    <b:elseif cond='data:blog.pageType == "error_page"'/>
        Page not found.
    <b:elseif cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'/>
        No posts.
    </b:if>
<b:else/>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.searchLabel'>
        Posts for label: <b expr:data-search="data:blog.searchLabel"/>.
    <b:elseif cond='data:blog.searchQuery'/>
        Posts for query: <b expr:data-search="data:blog.searchQuery"/>.
    </b:if>
</b:if>
```

`<data:blog.searchLabel/>` and `<data:blog.searchQuery/>` are unsafe tags so better print them via CSS.

```css
b[data-search]::after {
    content: attr(data-search);
}
```

Comment: What does it mean by unsafe tags?

Comment: These tags prints not escaped HTML entities.